# Transition from modal view to next view controller in modal's parent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have MyViewControllerA which was pushed into view by a navigation controller.  MyViewControllerA displays MyModalViewController.  MyModalViewController has a button where once pressed will push MyViewControllerB ontop of MyViewControllerA.  I created a delegate so MyModalViewController can tell MyViewControllerA that a button was a pressed so MyViewControllerA can place MyViewControllerB ontop of it.

Is there a clean way to transition from MyModalViewController to MyViewControllerB.  I tried to dismiss the modal view after pushing MyViewControllerB, but it does not give me that smooth animation when you normally drill down with a nav controller.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have delegate that can tell `ControllerA` about the button press. Now what you have to do is have a  flag in `ControllerA` (which will we use to tell A about the button press):

1. Initially set this flag false (in `viewDidLoad`).
2. Write `pushController` code for B in A's `viewWillAppear` method with checking:

   ```
   if(flag)
       push B.
   ```
3. When you press the button in `modalViewController` set this flag and dismiss that.
4. When this view will be dismissed then your `viewWillAppear` method will be called and it will push B if flag is set.

If still animation is not smooth then please use `viewDidAppear` method rather than `viewWillAppear`.

Thanks.